# How to clear a block element after floated divs without extra markup?

Tags: html, css, css-float, margin

I have two floated divs, after them I have a block element with margin-top. Unfortunately the `margin-top` doesn't work because of the float. Is it possible to add `margin-top` without extra markup in the code?

I tried with `:after`, but didn't help.

```
div {
    background-color: red;
}
#left {
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
#right {
    float: right;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
#content {
    margin-top: 50px;
    height: 100px;
    clear: both;
}

#content:before {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: table;
}

<div id="left">left</div>
<div id="right">left</div>
<div id="content">left</div>
```

```css
div {
    background-color: red;
}
#left {
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
#right {
    float: right;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
#content {
    margin-top: 50px;
    height: 100px;
    clear: both;
}

#content:before {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
```

```html
<div id="left">left</div>
<div id="right">left</div>
<div id="content">left</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, those collapsing margins...

If you change the top margin on the last div to a bottom margin on the top two divs, it works as expected.

```css
div {
  background-color: red;
}
#left {
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
#right {
  float: right;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
#content {
  height: 100px;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="left">left</div>
<div id="right">right</div>
<div id="content">content</div>
```

Comment: Yes, it's true, but why doesn't work it on the #content div?

Comment: @user1452062 Because of the way that `clear` works: it sets the top margin for `#content` to such a value that the div ends up just below the floating elements. Even setting `margin-top` to an very large value, say 1000px, wouldn't do anything; it just isn't used.

Comment: @user1452062  As evidence that it's the `clear` causing it, try removing the `clear` from your own snippet. Then you'd see that the margin does get applied. Except that it gets applied to both the floating divs as well, so that would not be a good solution!